# How to send emails from my server with a mail server and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, postfix-mta, nodemailer

I have a server with static IP in my home, I serve my own web pages with a domain and all works fine.

in my web pages, you can register by email and password. when you register a node module called nodemailer, sends an email from a google account, the problem is that the google account has a limit of the sent emails.

so I need to connect the nodemailer module to a server in my own home.

I search on google but nothing similar has the answer.

how to use postfix with nodejs??

http://www.postfix.org/

or how to use haraka module with nodemailer

https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka

so I repeat my question, I need to send an email from my server to any email user that register in my web.

for example...

user jose@gmail.com register in my web

nodemailer configuration is...

```
exports.newRegistration=function(parametros,callback)
{
    var mailOptions = 
    {
        from: "<myemailingoogle@gmail.com>",//my email
        to: parametros.useremail,//user email
        subject: 'Welcome '+parametros.useremail+'.',
        html:   '<br><b>Hello</b><br>'+ // html 

    };
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",
    {
        service: "Gmail",
        secureConnection: true,
        auth:
        {
            user: "myemailingoogle@gmail.com",
            pass: "7ftera359c28a",
        },
    });
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, response)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            smtpTransport.close();
            console.warn(err);
            return callback(err,null);
        }else{
            smtpTransport.close();
            return callback(null,response);
        }
    });
}
```

the email sends ok, but it has a limit per day.

so I need to use an email server to send my emails with no limit.... tnx

EDIT 2

i install mailutils with apt-get

and now i try

```
mail mymailin@gmail.com
Cc: // press enter
Subject: Welcome

Hello Mail.

// Ctrl+D
```

this sends emails to my mailbox and I receive in SPAM an email sent from root@mail.mydomain.com

so, postfix is working, but I still can't send emails with emailjs or nodemailer...

when I try to send emails with emails or nodemailer I get this

```
smtp: '535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure\n'
```

I search in google that error and is and auth login error, I can't login to the system.
so I try with telnet

```
telnet localhost 25
ehlo localhost
250-mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail to: myuserin@gmail.com
501 5.5.4 Syntax: MAIL FROM:<address>
mail from: info@mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: myuserin@gmail.com
451 4.3.0 <myuserin@gmail.com>: Temporary lookup failure
data
554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
AUTH LOGIN
503 5.5.1 Error: MAIL transaction in progress
```

I try again

```
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
UbuntuUser
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication
```

and again with root

```
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
root
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
rootPassword
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication
```

this is the log file

```
Jun 20 15:50:16 myname postfix/smtpd[12528]: warning: localhost[127.0.0.1]:             SASL login authentication failed: another step is needed in authentication
```

and that's it... where is the problem in this???

Answer (score 7):

I just had to do this as well, but I am running my node server on an Azure virtual Ubuntu Linux server. I imagine the same steps would work from your home server if you're running Ubuntu. Here is what I found worked:

I installed the postfix email server using this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

It looked like a lot of work at first, but it worked for me pretty easily.

I found the easiest way to send the outgoing email from node.js was to use emailjs:

http://github.com/eleith/emailjs.git

I found that emails sent often end up being marked as spam. To help avoid this, you can go to wherever you manage your domain name (I use enom) and then configure an SPF record to help make your outgoing email look legit.

Here is my node.js module to send emails using emailjs:

```
    var email   = require("emailjs");

    postfixSend = function postfixSend(emailInfo, callback) {

        var server  = email.server.connect({
            user:    "yourEmailAccountUser", 
            password: "yourPassword", 
            host:    "localhost", 
            ssl:     false
        });

        server.send({
            text:    emailInfo.msg, 
            from:    emailInfo.from, 
            to:      emailInfo.to,
            subject: emailInfo.subject
            }, function(err, message) {
                callback(err);
        });

    }

    exports.postfixSend = postfixSend;
```

Comment: i have an error: { [Error: authorization.failed]
  code: 3,
  previous:
   { [Error: bad response on command 'N2Z0ZXJhMzU5YzI4YQ==']
     code: 2,
     smtp: '535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure\n' },
  smtp: undefined }

Answer (score 1):

i solve de problem with this...

[article using postfix](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#auxprop_sasldb)

i add some users in the sasldb2 and the emailjs works pretty well.

first of all install the postfix using the [Svbaker tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) but,

edit /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf adding the following lines instead:

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb 
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```

thnx all your help, specially @Svbaker and serve you the solution to this problem.